# Why Java Beans have to be serializable?

Tags: java, javabeans

Is it necessary that a Java Bean implements the `Serializable` interface?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's one of the "typical" features as described in the [Javabeans specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/docs/spec.html).

Here's an extract of chapter **2.1 What is a bean?**

> Individual Java Beans will vary in the functionality they support, but the typical unifying features
>   that distinguish a Java Bean are:
>
> - Support for “introspection” so that a builder tool can analyze how a bean works
> - Support for “customization” so that when using an application builder a user can
>     customize the appearance and behaviour of a bean.
> - Support for “events” as a simple communication metaphor than can be used to connect
>     up beans.
> - Support for “properties”, both for customization and for programmatic use.
> - Support for persistence, so that a bean can be customized in an application builder and
>     then have its customized state saved away and reloaded later.

And here's an extract of chapter **5.5 Summary of Persistence**:

> All beans must support either Serialization or Externalization.

In practice, it's not explicitly necessary for it to function. It will in general also just work fine without implementing [`Serializable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). It's however useful whenever you'd like to store them "plain" on harddisk or send "plain" over network. For example when it's a session scoped bean which is to be stored in the HTTP session and the server is been confugured to persist and revive HTTP sessions during shutdown/restart. At any way, whenever you face a [`NotSerializableException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) with the bean's full qualified classname in the message, then it's enough sign to let it implement `Serializable`.

Comment: What about the `ApplicationScoped` beans, should they implement Serializable interface ?

Answer (score 14):

**Yes**.

By definition - a Java bean is exactly that, a *serializable* POJO (plain old Java object), with a no-argument constructor and private fields with getters/setters.